# How to get the current buffer file path using the Neovim Lua API?

Tags: lua, neovim

I am using Neovim 0.5 and want to write a custom function to use with `telescope.nvim`.

I need to get the path of the file loaded in the current buffer before I can execute the function. I have been unable to find how to do this after reading the Neovim Lua API documentation.

So far I've found that `vim.api.nvim_get_current_buf()` returns the current buffer number, but how do I get the full file path of the current buffer?

Answer (score 32):

You can access the full path to the file in the current buffer using `vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)`, where `0` for buffer id means *"the current buffer"*.

https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_buf_get_name()

Answer (score 25):

The function you are looking for is:

```
vim.fn.expand('%')
```

`%` is expanded to the current filename.

See `:help expand()` for more wildcards like `%`.

Comment: This is wrong. It may give a relative path.

Comment: For the absolute path, use `vim.fn.expand("%:p")` instead.

Answer (score 10):

```
vim.fn.expand('%:p')
```

Gives the full path regardless of the current path (CWD). Without the `%:p` modifier, it might give only the relative path. See `:help filename-modifiers` (or `%:p`)